# Algebraic Extensions and Tensorial Products

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field and $\mathbb K$ the algebraic closure  of $\mathbb F$. Denote by $M_n(\mathbb F)$ the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb F$. It is true that

$$M_n(\mathbb F)\otimes_{\mathbb F}\mathbb K\cong M_n(\mathbb K)?$$

If the answer is yes, what is the isomorphism explicitly?

Comment: you can use that $M_n({\Bbb{F}})\cong {\Bbb{F}}\oplus\cdots\oplus {\Bbb{F}}$ with  $n^2$-times ${\Bbb{F}}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider this two properties $({\Bbb{F}}\oplus\cdots\oplus {\Bbb{F}})\otimes_{{\Bbb{F}}}{\Bbb{K}}=({\Bbb{F}}\otimes_{{\Bbb{F}}}{\Bbb{K}})\oplus\cdots\oplus({\Bbb{F}}\otimes_{{\Bbb{F}}}{\Bbb{K}})$ and ${\Bbb{K}}={\Bbb{F}}\otimes_{{\Bbb{F}}}{\Bbb{K}}$.

Comment: do you know them??

Answer (score 1):

As usual with tensor products one can construct natural bilinear map $M_n(\mathbb{F}) \times \mathbb{K} $ to $M_n(\mathbb{K})$ and obtain a map $M_n(\mathbb{F}) \otimes \mathbb{K} \to M_n(\mathbb{K})$. Now you just need to understand its kernel and image, that is not hard...